# how to get call log for sim1, sim2 seperatly from an android activity?

Tags: android

I want to extract missed call, received call logs for sim1 or sim2 separately. I want to differentiate the call logs for different sims.
I have tried already extracted total call logs, but I'm unable to differentiate the sim slots in a dual sim environment.

This what i've tried:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
sb.append("Call Details :");

while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
    String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
    String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
    String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
    Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
    String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
    String dir = null;
    int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
    switch (dircode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            dir = "OUTGOING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            dir = "INCOMING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            dir = "MISSED";
            break;
    }
    sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
            + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
            + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
    sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
    Log.d(TAG_NAME,"\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
            + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
            + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);

    count++;

}
managedCursor.close();
Log.d(TAG_NAME,"Total Call Log count is "+count);
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: Please explain what the problem is with your code. Is the output not as expected, etc.

Comment: I'm using Dual sim Device. In that I want to extract only one sim call logs. where as I'm getting total call logs of the device.

Comment: you got solution...? if you get pls let me.

Answer (score 0):

Use SUB_ID constant value to get information about sim slots.

```
/**
 * The subscription ID used to place this call.  This is no longer used and has been
 * replaced with PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME/PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID.
 * For ContactsProvider internal use only.
 * <P>Type: INTEGER</P>
 *
 * @Deprecated
 * @hide
 */
 public static final String SUB_ID = "sub_id";
```

Use as CallLog.Calls.SUB_ID = "sub_id"