# Get dual sim phone call logs (Call Log Is from what Sim Card)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

We're creating a call log application and in a call log I want to show the user that the call log is from sim 1 or sim 2.
I found this but when I try to get it, it's null

```
curser.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID));
```

How can I find out the call log I get is from what sim card slot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify Call logs from Sim1 and Sim2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568563/identify-call-logs-from-sim1-and-sim2)

Answer (score 1):

For all those who are still looking for a solution, please try this code

First, you need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />` in your manifest file.

Second, you need to get the **SIM Subscription Id** associated with the **Call Log** using `curser.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID))`

Then pass the **SIM Subscription Id** to this function -

```
fun getSimInfoSubscriptionId(id: String): Int {
    var simSlotIndex = -1

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // Get subscription id's of all active sim's
            val subscriptionList = subscriptionManager.activeSubscriptionInfoList

            for (subscription in subscriptionList) {
                // If id is equal to the subscriptionId then assign the simSlotIndex
                if (subscription.subscriptionId.toString() == id) {
                    simSlotIndex = subscription.simSlotIndex
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return simSlotIndex
}
```

If `simSlotIndex = 0` then it is **SIM 1** or if `simSlotIndex = 1` then it is **SIM 2** :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo

Your code:

```
curser.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID));
```

The "e" in "curs**e**r" should be changed to "o"

Code without typo:

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID));
```